# Can I overclock an i3-3220 and Geforce GT 640?

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking, intel-core-i3

My current build:

- Gigabyte H61M-S2P Motherboard
- Intel Core i3-3220 @ 3.30 GHz
- Kingston Value Ram 8GB 1333 MHz
- Gigabyte GT 640 2GB OC Edition
- 1366 x 768 Resolution

I heard that there's no way to overclock the i3-3220, is it true?

Comment: If you want to overclock, I recommend a CPU with "K" at the end of the name. That ensures that it is unlocked for overclocking. Otherwise the CPU is [locked](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/282189-29-overclocking-intel-core-3220). For Intel, you would also want a Z series motherboard, not H.

Comment: The CPU you have is locked;

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar processor (Intel Core i3-3240 @ 3.4 GHz) and from my knowledge, this class of processors (especially the Core i3) are locked from the factory and cannot be overclocked in any way.

If you want to overclock, a suitable processor will be required. Core i5 and i7 CPUs ending with the letter 'K' (e.g. **i5-3570K**) are suitable for overclocking.

It seems that your video card could be overclocked, as is the [OC edition](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/review/graphics-cards/gigabyte-geforce-gt-640-oc-review-3375822/). Search for guides on overclocking your video card. (*Not recommended if you don't have experience about overclocking*).

Comment: @pratt_korp Thank you for changes. I've just noticed how bad my answer was in grammar terms.